# Running python script with dependencies on libraries from a virtualenv

Tags: python, numpy, path, scipy, virtualenv

I'm trying to run a naive bayes script that needs NumPy, SciPy and Pandas to run. To avoid the confusion with the multiple copies of python on Macs 10.7 --and because I couldn't figure out how to, really - I made a virtualenv and installed NumPy and SciPy there, checking that after running

```
$ python
>>> import numpy
>>> import scipy
```

everything works. Now, I'm in my file's directory, and running `python nb_predict.py` gives me a bunch of errors.

Originally, the path to my python compiler at the top of my file was

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
```

but since I didn't know if it had changed after installing everything in the virtual env, I've tried it with:

```
#!/Users/myusername/.virtualenvs/scipy/bin/python
```

and it still doesn't work. I've made the script executable, also.

Please, any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is what I get as the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "nb_predict.py", line 3, in <module>
    from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

  File "/Users/myusername/.virtualenvs/scipy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.15_git-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/sklearn/naive_bayes.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .preprocessing import binarize

  File "/Users/myusername/.virtualenvs/scipy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.15_git-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/sklearn/preprocessing/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .imputation import Imputer

  File "/Users/myusername/.virtualenvs/scipy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.15_git-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/sklearn/preprocessing/imputation.py", line 10, in <module>

    from scipy import stats
  File "/Users/myusername/.virtualenvs/scipy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.14.0.dev_572aaf0-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/scipy/stats/__init__.py", line 332, in <module> from .stats import *

  File "/Users/myusername/.virtualenvs/scipy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.14.0.dev_572aaf0-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/scipy/stats/stats.py", line 181, in <module>
    import scipy.special as special

  File "/Users/myusername/.virtualenvs/scipy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.14.0.dev_572aaf0-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/scipy/special/__init__.py", line 532, in <module>
from ._ufuncs import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/myusername/.virtualenvs/scipy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.14.0.dev_572aaf0-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/scipy/special/_ufuncs.so, 2): Symbol not found: ___sincos_stret

  Referenced from: /Users/myusername/.virtualenvs/scipy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.14.0.dev_572aaf0-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/scipy/special/_ufuncs.so
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /Users/myusername/.virtualenvs/scipy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.14.0.dev_572aaf0-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/scipy/special/_ufuncs.so
```

Comment: `#!...site-package` can't possibly work because `site-package` is a directory (not a program). You could try `#!/Users/myusername/.virtualenvs/scipy/bin/python` If it works then you could use `#!/usr/bin/env python` shebang and run the script while the virtualenv is active or write `setup.py` using `setuptools`' entry points to generate scripts with correct shebang automatically.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant. I ran it using "#!/Users/myusername/.virtualenvs/scipy/bin/python" and it returned the errors above.

Comment: I feel kind of wary trying to write a config or setup script, and I'd like to know what's causing the errors. It is a path/routing problem?

Comment: Does `python -mnumpy.distutils.system_info` finish successfully? Does `which python` point to `/Users/.../python`? This -> `Symbol not found: ___sincos_stret` looks important.

Comment: `-mnumpy.distutils.system_info` gives me a lot of information, and returns NOT AVAILABLE for most of them, but I'm not sure what that means, since importing numpy gives me no problems. `which python` does point to the second shebang I have (the one that includes my .virtualenv directory). Thanks for the help.

Comment: the commands are to assert the obvious (what `numpy` installation on which python are used). Googling `___sincos_stret` shows that `scipy` installation might be fixed if you recompile it with correct Xcode version. Have you tried [homebrew](http://www.lowindata.com/2013/installing-scientific-python-on-mac-os-x/)?